# Replace XMLReader with WebClient

Tags: c#

I would like to replace my XMLreader with a WebClient.

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
                settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore;

                XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/business/rss.xml, settings);
                SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
                reader.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public MainPage()
{
    // our web downloader
    WebClient downloader = new WebClient();

    // our web address to download, notice the UriKind.Absolute
    Uri uri = new Uri("http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/business/rss.xml", UriKind.Absolute);

    // we need to wait for the file to download completely, so lets hook the DownloadComplete Event
    downloader.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(FileDownloadComplete);

    // start the download
    downloader.DownloadStringAsync(uri); 
}

// this event will fire if the download was successful
void FileDownloadComplete(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // e.Result will contain the files byte for byte

    // your settings
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore;

    // create a memory stream for us to use from the bytes of the downloaded file
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(e.Result ?? ""));

    // create your reader from the stream of bytes
    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(ms, settings);

    // do whatever you want with the reader
    // ........

    // close
    reader.Close()
}
```